# Combinatoric - How many ways are?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We making package of 9 items. 
Package must contain 4 items of set **A** and 5 items of set **B**.

$A=\{x,y,z...\}$ - size of set A is 15 items

$B=\{d,e,..,H,G\}$ - size of set B is 17 items

How many ways are to compilation package, if $H$ may be included to both $A$ and $B$ set and every package must contain $G$ ?

So if $H$ may be included to both $A$ and $B$:

$A=\{x,y,z...,H\}$ - size is 16 items

$B=\{d,e,..,H,G\}$ - size is still 17 items

It is 2 possibilities:

a) choose H from A, G from B

b) chose H, G from B

All ways for choosing are
$\binom{15}{3}\binom{1}{1}\binom{15}{4}\binom{1}{1}+\binom{15}{4}\binom{15}{3}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1}=1242150$

Is that correct?

Comment: Will you please clarify whether $H$ can be there **simultaneously** in both $A$ and $B$ , i.e. there are 2 copies of $H$ ?

Comment: Yes H can be simultaneously in both A and B

Comment: And can we select $H$ from both $A$ and $B$, i.e. $2 H's$ in the packet ?

Comment: Not only one $H$ can be in packet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Revised answer in view of OP's clarifications*

You almost got it right, but the mistake is that you made choice of $H$ compulsory.

We need to correct that, and since $G$ is compulsory, we can just exclude it it, and take that we want $4$ each from $A$ and $B$

Apart from $H$, $15$ elements each are to be considered in the $2$ sets,
and we might not select $H$ at all, or select it from $A\;$ XOR $B$

You did not consider the case when $H$ is not selected at all, so just add $\binom{15}4\binom{15}4$ to your answer

**1242150 + 1863225 = 3105375**

Comment: So $2\times\binom{16}{4}\binom{15}{4} = 4968600$ is count of all ways or only in cause $H \in A$ ?

Comment: I have revised the answer in view of your clarifications.

Comment: I am not sure where I put $\binom{15}4\binom{15}4$ Please can you specify. It is $5796700 + \binom{15}4\binom{15}4$ all ways to compilation package?

Comment: I have specified now at the end of the answer.

Comment: So my answer was almost right. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If $H \in A$, then $|A| = 16, |B| = 17$, and then the number of ways to make a package is
$$\binom{1}{1}\times\binom{16}{4}\times\binom{16}{4} = 3312400.$$
In other words, there is one way to pick $G$, since it **must** be in the package. Then I am free to choose 4 from $A$, and 4 from the **remaining** 16 items in $B$.

If $H\not\in A$, then $|A| = 15, |B| = 17$, and then the number of ways to make a package is
$$\binom{1}{1}\binom{15}{4}\binom{16}{4} = 2484300.$$
In other words, there is one way to pick $G$, since it **must** be in the package. Then I am free to choose 4 from $A$, and 4 from the **remaining** 16 items in $B$.

Summing the two gives $5796700$ ways.

Comment: If $H \in A, |B| = 16$

Comment: No, not according to the given information. The original problem says the $B$ contains $H$ **no matter what**. The original information implies that if $H$ is in $A$, then it is in both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The given information seems contradictory to me. Anyway, I have asked OP for a clarification. Btw, if what you say is correct, how have you ensured that $H$ is not selected twice ?

Comment: I agree, the problem was a bit convoluted. Selecting $H$ twice does not matter since the only criterion was that $G$ **must** be selected. Also, if the correct interpretation is yours, then your answer is best. That's obvious, and it was probably the point of the problem. Using symmetry.

Comment: I guess we need to wait for OP's clarifications.